# Picker is not binding old selected value when coming back from next screen?

Tags: xamarin.android, spinner, xamarin.forms, dropdown, picker

I am working on xamarin.forms for android app. I created a picker on first screen and customize it with help of spinner and custom renderer. Its looking fine and working.

But when I moved on second screen and if I come back from second screen to first screen, picker doesn't show the old selected value. It shows only default first value.

I tried to find the problem and I got that when user come back to first screen, the position of picker elements index is 0. I am not getting why it is showing 0.

I am using following code in custom renderer:

```
 Picker picker;
    Spinner spinner;
    IList<string> scaleNames;
    ArrayAdapter<string> scaleAdapter;
    protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<Picker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged (e);
        if (e.OldElement != null || Element == null) {
            return;
        }
        picker = e.NewElement;
        scaleNames = e.NewElement.Items;
        spinner = new Spinner (this.Context);

        spinner.ItemSelected += new EventHandler<AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs> (spinner_ItemSelected);

        scaleAdapter = new  ArrayAdapter<string> (this.Context, Resource.Layout.view_spinner_item, scaleNames);
        scaleAdapter.SetDropDownViewResource (Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);
        spinner.SetBackgroundResource (Resource.Drawable.pickerControl);
        spinner.Adapter = scaleAdapter;

        base.SetNativeControl (spinner);
    }

    private void spinner_ItemSelected (object sender, AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        picker.SelectedIndex = (e.Position);
        if (picker.SelectedIndex != 0) {
            scaleAdapter = new  ArrayAdapter<string> (this.Context, Resource.Layout.view_spinner_selected_item, scaleNames);
            scaleAdapter.SetDropDownViewResource (Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);
            //spinner.Background = this.Resources.GetDrawable (Resource.Drawable.pickerControl);
            spinner.SetBackgroundResource (Resource.Drawable.pickerControl);
            spinner.Adapter = scaleAdapter;
            spinner.SetSelection (picker.SelectedIndex);

        } 

    }
```

Do you have any idea how I can set the value of picker so that when I come back to screen it shows me same value.

Comment: Have you tried to store the value in a global variable?

Comment: How are you navigating to the new screen? Are you using the NavigationPage?

Comment: @Joe,no actually all the screens are only one page. I have a grid array object in which all screens are bind. When user wants to move next screeen I bind the next grid array value in Content. And when user wants back I put previous grid array value in Content.